# strongloop loopback: how to save many-to-many relationship

Tags: postgresql, many-to-many, loopbackjs

I have the following relationship defined:

```
{
  "name": "playlist",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "relations": {
    "songs": {
      "type": "hasAndBelongsToMany",
      "model": "song",
      "foreignKey": ""
    } 
  }  
}
```

So a `Song hasAndBelongsToMany Playlist`. So far so good.

But when it comes to adding songs to a playlist, I am confused.

Ideally I'd like, for example, to be able to add the new songs in the same call of the playlist `create` endpoint. I have no idea how to do that, and the docs are quite poor imho.

It seems I have to do a `POST` on `/playlists/:id/songs` in order to associate songs to playlists? But then, I don't want to create new songs, just add existing songs to a playlist. Would that work this way? Wouldn't a `POST` at the mentioned URL add (and wanting to create) new songs?

BTW, using `postgresql` as backend.
What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship Loopback exposes add and remove JS methods as [documented](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/HasAndBelongsToMany+relations). However I can't find any documentation on how it is exposed in the API, but [this pull request](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-datasource-juggler/pull/161) explains how to do it as follows:

- Add a song to a playlist: `PUT /api/playlist/:id/song/rel/:fk`
- Remove a song from a playlist: `DELETE /api/playlist/:id/song/rel/:fk`

Note that this assumes that you have a `PlaylistSong` link table and Loopback Model, with PlaylistId and SongId fields and all of the correct relationships set up.

Comment: That's what I finally did, but server side:
`instance.songs.remove(song);`
`instance.songs.add(song);`

Comment: It was: *instance.songs.remove(song.id);* in my case